# Match all valid RTSP URL, what is the URL specification with authentication?

Tags: python, regex

My current regex looks like this: `r"rtsp://\w+:\w+@[\w\.-]+"`. My programming language is Python.

However some of the URLs look like this and it does not get matched:

```
rtsp://admin:fjs!hfk@my-cam.fritz.box/xxx/yyyy/1?transportmode=unicast
```

I can change the regex to `r"rtsp://\w+:[\w!]+@[\w\.-]+"` to match the `!`. I don't care about the end of the URL (`/xxx/yyyy/1?transportmode=unicast`)

The question I have is is there a specification what kind of characters the `<user>`, `<password>` and `<hostname>` can be? Because I'm probably not matching everything. I keep adding characters to the `\w` but I don't want to keep doing quick fixes like how I added the `!` to the password and `-` and `.` to the hostname.
Is it possible for someone to have a `@` in the password? I would need to handle that as well.

I will add the capturing groups that extract user, password and hostname at a later stage.

Comment: This is not bound to RTSP - i.e. in HTTP and FTP addresses can also carry user credentials, see https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1738 paragraph 3.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mess with regular expressions here, it has already been done for you:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse
obj = urlparse('rtsp://admin:fjs!hfk@my-cam.fritz.box/xxx/yyyy/1?transportmode=unicast')
print(obj)
```

This yields

```
ParseResult(scheme='rtsp', netloc='admin:fjs!hfk@my-cam.fritz.box', path='/xxx/yyyy/1', params='', query='transportmode=unicast', fragment='')
```

Now, you may just use the attributes:

```
print(obj.netloc)
# admin:fjs!hfk@my-cam.fritz.box
```

See [**the help page for more information**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/urllib.parse.html).

Comment: Thanks. That's perfect. Username, password and hostname are available through `obj.username`, `obj.password` and `obj.hostname`